# Unable to reach Landscape GUI in browser

Tags: juju, landscape

I have a virtual environment hosting 4 VMs:

- 1 for Maas (working)
- 1 for Juju-Gui (working)
- 1 for Landscape (not working)

The Juju GUI has been installed via juju using the following command:

```
sudo juju deploy juju-gui --to 0
```

and it's working right (see image below)

[image: Juju GUI]

I added a second VM to juju environment with:

```
sudo juju add-machine ssh:UbuntuLandscapeGui.maas -e maas
```

Finally, I added Landscape on that node:

```
sudo juju deploy cs:trusty/landscape-server-13
```

As in the image above, Landscape has been deployed correctly but when I try to open its the web interface I get the following:

[image: Landscape Web UI]

I obtained the same result using either the IP or hostname. I can reach both VMs via ping

[image: ping]

Is any other configuration required in Juju to successfully deploy the Landascape charm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup instructions for Landscape Dedicated Server include steps to install the service via Juju, see:

https://help.landscape.canonical.com/?action=show&redirect=LDS

Comment: I'm not using juju-quickstart, I realized the environment via juju-core and juju-gui, anyway I've found it on the store. I try it and then inform you if it works.

Comment: How do I have to make to place LDS on a my selected machine on juju-gui? As you suggested me juju creates a new machine. I can't decide where to deploy that.